# Admob angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Does anyone know how to install and use the "AdMob" plugin on angularjs? I have a project in ionic and I wanted to add this plugin but it has to be in the angle, it can not be in the .ts files, since I have already seen several tutorials with the .ts files.

But my project was first created in the ionic creator, and then I started programming on top of that project. And it just has a .ts file that is in the home. But I do not use the .ts files in development. I directly create the files in the www folder. Hence my problem in not being able to add the plugin in the .ts file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Admob plugin in any .ts file. Please refer to the official documentation of ionic for [Admob integration](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-pro/).

Or

You can refer to this [LINK](https://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-google-admob-advertisements-in-ionic/) for detailed instructions on how to integrate Admob in Ionic app.

For app made using ionic creator, this [TUTORIAL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbtzhwtr0kc) may help.

Comment: But my project was first created in the ionic creator, and then I started programming on top of that project. And it just has a .ts file that is in the home. But I do not use the .ts files in development. I directly create the files in the www folder. Hence my problem in not being able to add the plugin in the .ts file Thanks

Comment: i have updated the answer.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. It does not show the banner, but it does not give an error.

Comment: may be there's some error in the ad or id.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Already worked

Comment: is my answer helpful??

Comment: Yes, the id was wrong. Thanks

Comment: Please mark as right answer if my answer did help you :)